# 'The person whom I ask for help is clever'

Tags: whom

Does 'whom' work here?

> The person **whom** I ask for help is clever.

I don't think it does: **ask for** has already an object.

Comment: Consider *I ask **him/her** for help.*

Comment: This is why nobody should ever use _whom_. What good does it do you to use it, even if you use it right, when nobody can tell whether it's right or not? _Who_ always works, as it would here.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the word "whom". The sentence is just a peculiar expression. Consider, "He whom I ask is clever." It just sounds very forced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person you're asking is the *direct* object of *ask*, and the help is an *indirect* one, so *whom* is the correct (objective) case.

However, I would - even though *whom* is perfectly correct - counsel leaving it out altogether and just writing one of:

- The person I ask for help is clever
- The person I am asking for help is clever
- I ask a clever person for help
- I am asking a clever person for help
- I have a clever friend I go to for help
  …

depending on which you mean.

Comment: Had forgotten the direct object. This shed light on my question.